# Freeing ImageData when deleting a Canvas

Tags: html, memory-leaks, canvas, xul, bitmapimage

I'm writing a XUL application using HTML Canvas to display Bitmap images. 
I'm generating ImageDatas and importing them in a canvas using the putImageData function :

```
  for(var pageIndex=0;pageIndex<100;pageIndex++){
   this.img = imageDatas[pageIndex];

   /* Create the Canvas element */
   let imgCanvasTmp = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",'html:canvas');
   imgCanvasTmp.setAttribute('width', this.img.width);
   imgCanvasTmp.setAttribute('height', this.img.height);

   /* Import the image into the Canvas */
   imgCanvasTmp.getContext('2d').putImageData(this.img, 0, 0);

   /* Use the Canvas into another part of the program (Commented out for testing) */
  // this.displayCanvas(imgCanvasTmp,pageIndex);
  }
```

The images are well imported but there seems to be a memory leak due to the putImageData function.

When exiting the "for" loop, I would expect the memory allocated for the Canvas to be freed but, by executing the code without executing putImageData, I noticed that my program at the end uses 100Mb less (my images are quite big).

I came to the conclusion that the putImageData function prevents the garbage collector freeing the allocated memory.

Do you have any idea how I could force the garbage collector to free the memory? Is there any way to empty the Canvas?

I already tried to delete the canvas using the delete operator or to use the clearRect function but it did nothing.

I also tried to reuse the same canvas to display the image at each iteration but the amount of memory used did not changed, as if the image where imported without deleting the existing ones...

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/debugging_memory_leaks) may help

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the canvas after the loop. Looking at your code, `imgCanvasTmp` is still reachable, and can't be garbage collected. Note that you might need to let the browser idle for a few minutes before the garbage collector to kick in. Also, maybe you want to clear `imageDatas` too.

Comment: After posting my question I tried to declare "imgCanvasTmp" with let keyword so that it will stay in the loop scope but it does not work neither. (I edit my code).
I also tried to store the canvas into this.imgCanvasTmp and delete it at the end using delete(this.imgCanvasTmp) but I still had memory leak.
I don't think imageDatas is the problem, since I have no memory leak when taking out the putImageData() function...